# Create a form to get user information for payment gateway

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to develop a plugin for an online gateway which is using wsdl method to connect it.

I found an article on how to build a woocommerce payment gateway plugin.
This is the link:
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/build-woocommerce-payment-gateway-plugin/

In this line shows a default form to get card number, cvv2 and expire date, but I need to get more data, such as number of installment:

$this->supports = array( 'default_credit_card_form' );

so I need to create a custom form instead of default credit card form to get my own custom fields such as "number of installment" field.

I tried to find something about this on the internet but unfortunately I could not find anything.
I would be grateful if anyone could guide me how to add custom field or build a new form with the fields that I need.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and I put here for anyone who want to this:

For showing custom fields below codes should add to function payment_fields:

```
public function payment_fields(){
    if ( $description = $this->get_description() ) {
        echo wpautop( wptexturize( $description ) );
    }
    ?>
    <div id="custom_input">
        <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="TedadGhest" class="">
        <?php _e('number of installment', 'oti_iran_hekmat'); ?>
    </label>
            <select name="TedadGhest" id="TedadGhest">
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
    </select>
        </p>
</div>
    <?php
}
```